# Beep when typing backslash in cvim normal mode

Tags: vim, editors, vi, ide, plugin

I installed the cvim plugin for vim.

Almost all the cvim commands start with '`\`'.

But I when enter this character in normal mode, all I hear is a beep. Nothing happens. What might be causing this problem?

Comment: Maybe adding a link to this plugin would help.

Answer (score 1):

the \ is the default <leader> key, used to prefix commands.

You have to type the entire cvim command pretty quickly, otherwise it times out and thinks you want to type something.

Press \, then type the rest of the cvim command.  For instance, the **\ct** command should insert the current date & time into your document.

No, I don't use this plugin. Good luck.